# "Invalid namespace" Error when trying to use NetQosPolicy in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to limit the network bandwidth for a certain application, I came across such a thing as NetQosPolicy. I started trying to create new policies through PowerShell, but kept getting this error:

> New-NetQosPolicy : New-NetQosPolicy : Invalid namespace string:1 character:1 + New-NetQosPolicy -Name TestPolicy -IPProtocolMatchCondition Both -Net ... + + CategoryInfo : MetadataError: (MSFT_NetQosPolicySettingData:ROOT/StandardCi...licySettingData) [New-Net QosPolicy], CimException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004100e,New-NetQosPolicy

I used this code: `New-NetQosPolicy -Name TestPolicy -IPProtocolMatchCondition Both -NetworkProfile All -ThrottleRateActionBitsPerSecond 1200000`

I thought I had made a mistake in the syntax and decided to look at the examples on the Microsoft website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netqos/new-netqospolicy?view=windowsserver2022-ps), but even their examples cause me the same error.

I haven't found a solution to this problem anywhere, so I'm asking on the forum. I will be grateful to anyone who knows how to solve this problem.

(By the way, I get the same error when I try to use the NetSecurity module (for example, the command: **New-NetFirewallRule**))

Comment: Does this command run for you or error out? Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\StandardCimv2 -Class MSFT_NetQosPolicySettingData

Comment: @MikeAnthony Error occurs

Answer (score 0):

You might have a corrupt wmi repo, read [this page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/wmi-missing-or-failing-wmi-providers-or-invalid-wmi-class/ba-p/375485) but start with this check

> Check if the repository is corrupted or not by running following command from command prompt with admin rights: winmgmt /verifyrepository

Comment: Well, my repository seems NOT to be corrupted (I am not getting any error messages using "winmgmt /verifyrepository"), so I don't think that might be a solution. Or maybe I misunderstood something, but I didn't find any errors. And even if it is corrupted, I do not know which repository is specifically broken.

Comment: @@MikeAnthony I also tried finding the source of problem using WMIDiag.vbs and got some logs. Here is one of them: [link](https://gist.github.com/Koshel4/0f40603d28419e2353d5199a733946dc)